# Makefile pattern matching not working as I expected

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to setup a simple Makefile for building a simple project that's not too hard to maintain.

I want to make use of pattern matching rules e.g. `%.o : %.c ; g++ ...` where I have all the object files I would want to compile deduced from wildcard matched source files.

The directory structure is

```
./src
./include
./build/bin
./build/objs
```

Right now my problem looks something like this.

```
INCL_DIR = ./include
SRC_DIR = ./src

BUILD_DIR = ./build
BIN_DIR = $(BUILD_DIR)/bin
OBJ_DIR = $(BUILD_DIR)/objs

SRCS = $(notdir $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cc))
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(SRCS:%.cc=%.o))

$(BIN_DIR)/program : $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I $(INCL_DIR) $^ -o $@

$(OBJS):%.o : %.cc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I $(INCL_DIR) -c $< -o $@
```

In the line `$(OBJS):%.o : %.cc` an example expansion would be from target rule `./build/objs/a.o` that depends on `./build/objs/a.cc` but the source file is in  `./src/a.cc`.

So I figured I could strip away the dependency format to try and match `./src/a.cc` but the utilies for text manipulations don't seem to work on the dependency side of a rule.

I tried something like

```
$(OBJS):%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/$(notdir %.cc)
```

or

```
$(OBJS):%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/$(*F).cc
```

where `$(*F)` would expand to `a` in the earlier example case but it doesn't expand to anything when listed as a dependency.

I'm not experienced with Makefiles and not sure why my attempts arent working and would very much like to hear a solution that might solve my issue.

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, which isn't entirely clear to me, you can't really use the pattern matching rules like this - you have to use the built-in string manipulation functions to create lists of dependencies. I have a couple of articles on generic makefiles at https://latedev.wordpress.com/2014/11/08/generic-makefiles-with-gcc-and-gnu-make/ which may or may not help.

Comment: Are you looking for something like:  `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c` ?

Comment: @John I believe that would expand to `./build/test.o : ./src/./build/test.cc` but should have depended on `./src/test.cc`. Also, I would prefer to use `$(OBJS)/%.o : ...`  because I might want to add files in further nested directories into OBJS.

Comment: No, it wouldn't.   The stem (`%` sign) for the target will be _exactly_ the same string as the stem for the prerequisite.   In this case the stem would be `test`.   So it would expand to: `./build/test.o: ./src/test.c`

Comment: @John Actually, that works perfectly, even for nested files. It seems like `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o` looks for matches in further nested directories, e.g. `$(OBJ_DIR)/UI/test.o` with the stem being `UI/test.o`. I have to say I'm surprised that it does that and would have thought I'd need to manually do `$(OBJ_DIR)/UI/%.o`.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?  If you have a string `./build/UI/test.o` and you match with the pattern `./build/%.o`, then clearly the stem (the part that matches `%`) would be `UI/test`... what else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is already in @John's comment. I will try to explain it in bit more detail. I will use an example with `hello.cc` in folder `src`.

pattern rules hold the pattern in `%` symbol. If there is in the makefile a pattern rule: `build/objs/%.o : src/%.cc` and you request to build file `build/objs/hello.o`, `%` will carry value `hello`. But if your pattern rule would be `$(OBJS):%.o : %.cc`, the pattern `%` will be `build/objs/hello` and the dependency file `build/objs/hello.cc` is missing (because it is saved in `src`, not in `build/objs`).

So solution for you would be:

```
$(OBJS):$(OBJ_DIR)%.o : $(SRC_DIR)%.cc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I $(INCL_DIR) -c $< -o $@
```

If you want to make sure how patterns work, you can print pattern content by adding line `@echo $*` to recipe.